# Reduce voltage, maintain current

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-charge-controller

I’ll be frank, I messed up.

I’m installing a solar system in my camper van and bought a combined solar MPPT charge controller and DC/DC charger. Unfortunately I didn’t notice the max solar input for the charge controller was 25v but my panel’s VOC is around 32v.

I’d appreciate any opinions on the most efficient way to step down the panels output voltage (whilst keeping the current as high as as possible) to keep it in range of the charge controller. I really don’t want to replace the entire unit as it wasn’t cheap… And obviously I want to harvest as much power from my panel as possible given the above limitations.

Comment: Most efficient? Obviously it needs to be a thing with MPPT input too to get the most out of the panels, but having two MPPTs in a row will bring down the efficiency so one MPPT is best. If you won't change the current MPPT, then best efficiency is achieved by changing the panels to have lower VOC. However isn't this question basically about (1) usage of electrical products and (2) asking for opinions (3) what to buy?

Comment: questions seeking an opinion are off topic here

Comment: If the controller came from a full-service distributor or manufacturer in your country, I'd start by calling them.  A company that wants to maintain its reputation will do things like giving very favorable exchanges in cases like this, especially if you haven't hooked anything up yet.  If not -- is that 25V the maximum nominal panel voltage, or the maximum voltage _ever_?  VOC is usually a lot higher than nominal panel voltage.

Comment: Since this is an electronics engineering design group -- if we give you a circuit along with the guidance "safety is up to you, don't blame us if you burn down your van" are you up to implementing it (or being wise enough to walk away?)

Comment: Noting that this question is either off-topic or seeks opinions, I would suggest you exchange/sell your merchandise to someone in a similar situation by advertising on a local group.

Answer (score 0):

If your panel controller really has an absolute maximum input voltage of 25V (and isn't just designed for panels with a nominal 25V output), then a carefully-selected buck converter will do it.

Buy or build a buck converter that can handle an output current of \$\frac{32}{24}\$ of the highest current you expect from the panel*, and that can be trusted** to hold its output close to the panel's output voltage for voltages lower than that magic \$25\mathrm V\$.

If you selected (or built) the thing correctly, then it'll pass the panel voltage through to the converter until the converter output voltage reaches \$25\mathrm V\$, at which point it'll hold the output at that voltage.

I'd put it somewhere that it'll get adequate cooling when it's running full blast.  The thing actually being used implies that it's hot out, so you *probably* want to vent that heat outside of the living quarters, unless you're only ever going to use the van when it's cold outside and extra heat will be welcome.

Note that this has the potential to confuse the @#$% out of the MPPT controller.

- If you're really lucky, if the operating conditions call for the thing to operate around 25V input then the MPPT controller will actually find the 25V & maximum current point.
- If you're merely lucky, the MPPT controller and the buck converter will oscillate lightly around this point, efficiency will be down a bit, and everything else will be fine.
- If you're unlucky, oscillations will break out and either some protection scheme will trigger, turning everything off.
- If you're really unlucky, **strong** oscillations will break out, and the equipment will announce its unhappiness by emitting very expensive-smelling smoke.

* Unless the controller limits its input current, read the panel literature *carefully*.  You want to size the converter for the most current it'll ever produce.  If that's not limited by the controller, it'll be limited by the panel, and that depends on the light input.  If I were designing a product I'd go with noon, summer solstice, right on a tropic in the desert sort of output.  If I were designing for *me* I might design for my rainy, temperate climate, knowing that if I go camping in Death Valley I'll have to throw a towel over the solar panel at noon.

** This is the hard part if you buy -- but it's sort of the default behavior of a simple buck converter, so you may be in luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I very much appreciate the info. The buck converter was something I was already considering so the info here supports that somewhat. I was unsure of how efficient it would be at passing current at the converted voltage but the answers are reassuring. The other low tech option I’m considering is covering a portion of the panel…

Comment: In fairness to myself most of the other MPPT controllers have much higher input ranges, I made a bad assumption and didn’t check. This was whilst completing the entire conversion from scratch so I had plenty of other things to be thinking about at the same time. I got the unit direct from the manufacturing company itself and they were surprisingly unhelpful. 

For a bit more background (as it was raised) I’m not an electronics engineer. I qualified as an electronics technician many, many years ago. And now work as an RF technician.

Comment: If you can configure your buck converter to run at a fixed duty cycle to just drop the voltage (i.e. remove the voltage regulation feedback), then the MPPT should still work.  I'll leave it to those with more practical experience with buck converters to suggest how.

Comment: @Tesla23: it would have to be a synchronous buck, though.  A buck converter that uses a diode would go into discontinuous conduction with light current demand, then its output would rise to close to the input voltage.

Comment: I'd look for a surplus Vicor or other name brand converter, BTW -- some cheap no-name converter off of Amazon has little chances of working up to ratings.  And pay attention to heat-sinking if it's a module that's designed to bolt onto something (like a Vicor).